Transfinite recursion (as in Kunen, theorem 9.3, chapter I).
I feel unsure about the proof of "Transfinite Recursion", as explicated in Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs" (thm 9.3, chapter I), and wants to check my understanding.
The statement goes as follows:

Let $\mathbf{F}:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V}$. Then there is a unique $\mathbf{G}:\mathbf{ON} \to \mathbf{V}$ such that $$\forall \alpha[\mathbf{G}(\alpha) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{G}\upharpoonright \alpha)]. \qquad \qquad (1)$$

For $\underline{\text{uniqueness}}$, explicating on Kunen, I (right now) believe the idea to be the following:
We proceed by induction on $\alpha \in \mathbf{ON}$, given $\mathbf{G}_1,\mathbf{G}_2:\mathbf{ON} \to \mathbf{V}$ satisfying $(1)$. For the base case $0$  since there are no elements in $0$, and we know that $\mathbf{G}_i(0) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{G}_i \upharpoonright 0)$, so that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{G}_i\upharpoonright 0)$ is really $\mathbf{F}(0)$, so that the $\mathbf{G}_i$ agree.
I believe we don't have to partition the induction into a limit and a successor-case, we can rather proceed as follows:
Assuming $(1)$ holds for $\mathbf{G}_i, i = 1,2$, and that $$\forall \beta < \alpha(\mathbf{G}_1(\beta) = \mathbf{G}_2(\beta)), \qquad \qquad (2)$$ we use $(1)$ to see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{G}_1(\alpha) &= \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{G}_1\upharpoonright \alpha)\\
&= \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{G}_2 \upharpoonright \alpha) \qquad \qquad (\text{by the inductive assumption $(2)$})\\
&= \mathbf{G}_2(\alpha).
\end{align*}
Here we also used that the restriction to of $\mathbf{G}_i$ to $\alpha$ is really all ordinals $\beta < \alpha$. My $\underline{\text{claim}}$ is that this shows uniqueness.
For $\underline{\text{existence}}$:
We call $g$ a $\delta$-approximation $\iff$ $g$ is a fct with domain $\delta$ and $$\forall \alpha < \delta[g(\alpha) = \mathbf{F}(g \upharpoonright \alpha)]. \qquad \qquad (3)$$
If we assume that $g$ is a $\delta$-approximation and $g'$ is a $\delta'$-approximation, so that $$\forall \alpha < \delta'[g'(\alpha) = \mathbf{F}(g' \upharpoonright \alpha)], \qquad \qquad (3')$$
then we want to show that $g_1 \upharpoonright \delta \cap \delta' = g_2 \upharpoonright \delta \cap \delta'$. It seems like we can do induction up to $\gamma$ for some ordinal $\gamma$ (instead of either transfinite induction, or induction for $\omega$; although I have never done this before, I don't think).
Assuming we can do transfinite induction up to $\gamma \in \mathbf{ON}$, take $\gamma = \delta \cap \delta'$. Then assume that $$\forall \alpha < \gamma[g_1(\alpha) = g_2(\alpha)]. \qquad \qquad (4)$$
Then we see that
\begin{align*}
g_1(\gamma) &= \mathbf{F}(g_1\upharpoonright \gamma)\\
&= \mathbf{F}(g_2 \upharpoonright \gamma) \qquad \qquad (\text{by $(4)$})\\
&= g_2(\gamma).
\end{align*}
Hence it holds that $g_1\upharpoonright \delta \cap \delta' = g_2 \upharpoonright \delta \cap \delta'$.
We then want to show that for each $\delta \in \mathbf{ON}$, there exists a $\delta$-approximation:
For $\delta = 0$, this is just $\mathbf{F}(0)$, which exists. Assume it holds for all $\alpha < \delta$ that $$\exists g_{\alpha}: \forall \zeta < \alpha [g_{\alpha}(\zeta) = \mathbf{F}(g_{\alpha} \upharpoonright \zeta)] \qquad \qquad (5).$$
The $g_{\alpha}$ is neccessarily unique by what we showed earlier.
If $\delta$ is a successor-ordinal, so that $\delta = \gamma+1$, then we know that there is a $\gamma$-approximation $g_{\gamma}$. Then we define $$g_{\delta}(\alpha) := \begin{cases} g_{\gamma}(\alpha), \text{if} \ \alpha < \gamma\\
\mathbf{F}(g_{\gamma} \upharpoonright \alpha), \text{if}\ \alpha = \gamma \end{cases}$$
If $\delta$ is a limit-ordinal, I believe it suffices to then define the $\delta$-approximation $g_{\delta}$ as $$g_{\delta} = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha < \delta} g_{\alpha}.$$ Since the $g_{\alpha}$ will neccessarily agree on the intersection of their domains by what we showed, it follows that $g_{\delta}$ will be left-total and right-unique, hence a fct. Furthermore, we know that for $\alpha < \delta$, we have \begin{align*} g_{\delta}(\alpha) &= g_{\zeta}(\alpha) \qquad \qquad(\text{for some $\zeta$ such that $\alpha < \zeta < \delta$})\\
&= \mathbf{F}(g_{\zeta} \upharpoonright \alpha)\end{align*} so that $g_{\delta}$ is a $\delta$-approximation.
Finally, one defines $\mathbf{G}(\alpha)$ as $g(\alpha)$ for some $\delta$-approximation $g_{\delta}$ such that $\delta > \alpha$. Is this correct? There are several steps I am unsure about.

Which steps are you unsure about? This looks completely correct to me. BTW you can combine the uniqueness of $G$ and uniqueness of $g_\delta$ into a single induction, which makes the proof much shorter. Prove via strong induction that the $g_\delta$ are unique whenever they exist, and then prove $G$ is unique (if it exists) by proving that $G\restriction_\delta = g_\delta$ satisfies as a $\delta$ approximation, for any $\delta$. That implies $G(\delta) = g_{\delta+1}(\delta)$, which gives uniqueness due to the previous induction.
